# Find the index of a certain value in array using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

Following the instructions reported in the documented swift manual
http://swift-ios.co/standard-functions-in-swift/

I found the code the extract the index of a certain value of an array using

```
var languages = ["Swift", "Objective-C"]
find(languages, "Objective-C") == 1
find(languages, "Java") == nil
find([29, 85, 42, 96, 75], 42) == 2
```

The problem is that the output value doesn' t have the same type of the elements os the starting array, since the output in the console is (for the last line)

```
Optional(2)
```

What if I want to get the 2 as `Int` or `Double`?

Comment: I do not understand the title. Can you change it to eliminate the misleading "max/min value"? Your question is not about that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Int?` (a.k.a. `Optional<Int>`). You need to extract `Int` from it. You can use `if-let` syntax

```
if let index = find([29, 85, 42, 96, 75], 42) {
    // index is Int
}
```

Comment: Note: `Optional<Int>` and `Int?` are different way to express the same thing: an optional. Reading your answer it looks like they are different instead. I would make that explicit, just to avoid confusion

Comment: @mstysf genius! It worked! I don't understand the type of export that find gives as output, why it shouldn't be just as the type of the value found in the array. Thank you so much anyway

Comment: Optionals are to deal with nothing case or error case. An optional value contains either a value or `nil`. In order to extract its value you need to use `if-let` syntax or `!` operator to force optional to unwrap. But you have to be careful when you use `!` operator. If optional value contains `nil` it will crash your program. In your case think about an array `[1,2,3,4,5]` and what happens when you call `find(array, 20)`. Because there is no '20' in array it is logical to return `nil`. Because `find` function can return `nil` or a value the return type is `Int?` not `Int`.